# Customizing eclipse CDT c++ new class template

Tags: eclipse, templates, customization, eclipse-cdt

I am using eclipse CDT Juno. Is it possible to customize C++ header and source files just after standard "New Class" dialog?

I want to change generated code a bit to include the copy constructor and assignment operator.

For example I want to add the following members to every generated class,
so resulting class will looks like:

```
class ClassName
{
public:
ClassName();
virtual ~ClassName();

private:
// ---------- What I want to add: begin ---------
ClassName(const ClassName&);
ClassName& operator=(const ClassName&);
// ---------- What I want to add: end ---------
};
```

Thanks

Comment: did you see the Eclipse reference about that: [Creating a project via a project template](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/tasks/cdt_t_proj_new_with_template.htm)

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I want to do nearly the same thing!

Comment: @jvriesem I haven't got any solution till now.